# Is there a way to set a field to be in the child objects scope, while being accessible from the parent object?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, scope, prototypal-inheritance

I'm doing some experiences with OOP in JavaScript. My goal is to have a parent object which holds methods common to several other objects, which inherit from that parent object. Thing is, I want the parent objects' methods to be able to read the childrens' fields.

I use the following function for inheritance:

```
Function.prototype.inherits=function(obj){this.prototype=new obj();}
```

These are some example objects:

```
function Genetic(c){
    this.code=c;
}
//My 'parent object':
function Animal(){
    this.getCode=function(){
        return(genetic.code);
    }
}
g=new Genetic('test');
function Dog(){
    genetic=g;
}
Dog.inherits(Animal);
g=new Genetic('foo');
function Cat(){
    genetic=g;
}
Cat.inherits(Animal);

d=new Dog();
c=new Cat();
```

Now, I expect `d.getCode()` to return `'test'`, and `c.getCode()` to return `'foo'`. Problem is, both return `'foo'`. The variable `genetic` is in the `Animal` scope, and not in the `Dog`/`Cat` scope. Meaning that whenever I create a new object that inherits from `Animal`, the `genetic` variable will be overridden. Proof:

```
function Bla(){}
Bla.inherits(Animal);
bla=new Bla()
bla.getCode() //Returns 'foo'
```

I can set the `genetic` variable to being a private variable of `Dog` and `Cat` with var:

```
function Dog(){
    var genetic=g;
}
```

Problem is, since `genetic` is now private to `Dog`, it can't be accessed by the `Animal` object, rendering the whole inheritance pointless.

Do you see any way to solve that?

EDIT: Also, I want `gentic` to be private, so that it can't be modified in `Dog`/`Cat` instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The variable 'genetic' is in the Animal scope, and not in the Dog/Cat scope.

No, `genetic` is **global**. There exists only one `genetic` variable in your whole application. Make it a property of the object.

Furthermore, a better way of inheritance is the following:

```
function inherits(Child, Parent) {
    var Tmp = function(){};
    TMP.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new Tmp();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
```

Then you can have the parent constructor accept arguments and don't have to repeat code:

```
//My 'parent object':
function Animal(g){
    this.genetic = g;
}

Animal.prototype.getCode = function() {
    return this.genetic.code;
}

function Dog(){
    Animal.apply(this, arguments);
}
inherits(Dog, Animal);

function Cat(){
    Animal.apply(this, arguments);
}
inherits(Cat, Animal);

var d = new Dog(new Genetic('test'));
var c = new Cat(new Genetic('foo'));
```

I would advice to [document your code properly](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) and rather follow a clear prototype/inheritance chain than trying to do something the language is not designed for.

However, with the `inherits` function given above, you could do:

```
function Animal(g){
    var genetic = g

    this.getCode = function(){
        return genetic.code ;
    }
}
```

with the rest of the code staying the same. Then you have your "private" variable at the cost of every instance having its own `getCode` function.

*Edit:* This would not let you access `genetic` in any function assigned to `Dog` or `Cat`, unless you also keep a reference to the value in their constructors.

Comment: You're right, but I want the variable to be private, so it can't be modified after creation! With the code you wrote, I could just do: d.genetic.code='whadup bro';

Comment: Ok, thanks, so what I tried to do is not possible... Could you please explain the difference of the `inherit` function you gave me?

Comment: @Alex: Your function assigns an `Animal` instance as prototype to `Cat` and `Dog`. This works, but only if `Animal` does not expect any arguments. My function assigns `Animal`'s prototype instead (via a temporary constructor to "decouple" the prototypes). You have to call the parent constructor in the children's constructor, but the relationship is cleaner. This is a common pattern used by various libraries.